# When trying to alter the query in Report Builder 3.0, I get error "Can not connect to database"

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012, builder

I'm using a virtual MS SQL Server hosted in Azure and using Report Builder 3. 
I created the report, and the report runs correctly. I've also gone into the data source and clicked Test Connection and it comes back successful.
I added a new field to the view that this report uses, and I want to add that new field to the report. When I refresh the fields I get the following error message.

> ### The network path was not found
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Thanks for any assistance!